# c program on 2d matrices crashes everytime

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

```
 int main(){
    int m1[3][3],m2[3][3],m3[3][3],m4[3][3],m5[3][3];
    create(m1);
    create(m2);
    matadd(m3,m1,m2);
    matmul(m4,m1,m2);
    transpose(m5,m4);
    getch();
    return 0;
  }

  void create(int a[3][3]){
    int i,k;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(k=0;k<3;k++)
           scanf("%d",a[i][k]);
        }
    }
```

m new at coding,have made a simple program on 2D matrices,compiles successfully but every time on running it crashes after i input 1st 2 integers calling 1st create().

Comment: What is `i/p` supposed to mean? "input"? Please talk in english, not lol-speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this way

```
scanf("%d", &a[i][k]);
```

Every time you take input/`scanf` you need to put `&`. this is the basic thing of C, how can you miss this?

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%d",a[i][k]);
```

`d` conversion specifier expects a pointer to `int` but you are passing an `int`.

To pass a pointer to the object use the `&` operator:

```
scanf("%d", &a[i][k]);
```